# Recursive call script

Tags: shell-script, scripting, recursive

I am trying to make a script that will list all files and directories in a given directory. I want to make this script to call itself, in the end showing all files and directories. I know that you can easily do that with ***find***, but I want to ***practice recursive scripts***, and I don't know why my recursive given parameter is not what I was expecting, it's value doesn't change.

```
for source in `find $1 -maxdepth 1 -type d,f`
do
        if [ -f $source ]; then
                echo "`basename $source` is a file"
        fi
        if [ -d $source ]; then 
                echo "`basename $source` is a directory"
                . Script.sh $source
        fi
done
```

Comment: Add `-mindepth 1` to your find. But follow DepressedDaniel's excellent advice

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The following line is the culprit:

```
. Script.sh $source
```

While you could conceivably do recursion that way, it makes it hard to reason about because the variables changed by the next level of recursion are changed in the caller as well. Probably you just want to invoke it without sourcing it:

```
Script.sh $source
```

Or, better yet:

```
"$0" "$source"
```

Reliably getting the source script in all cases is a bit tricky, though. Much better yet is to use functions to do recursion (in Bash):

```
function f()
{
   ...
   f different_args
   ...
}
```

And declare any variables used within `f` as `local` so they won't be mutated by the recursive call to `f`.