# Bash recursive call fails

Tags: shell-script, bashrc, recursive

I am writing a function in `./bashrc` to switch environment variables, commands, etc.  This function is supposed to set up the necessary variables then call itself.  Instead I get

```
bash: ./bash: No such file or directory
```

The function in my `.bashrc` script is this following:

```
switch() {
    EXISTS="$(ls ~/br/*$1 2> /dev/null)"
    if [ -z "EXISTS" ]; then
        BR="$1*"
        export PS1="...."
    else
        # Find "export BRANCH=" in .bashrc and replace it with input
        sed -i "0,/export/BRANCH=/{s/export BRANCH=.*$/export BRANCH\"$1\"/}" ~/.bashrc

        ./$0
    fi
}
```

I saw this post, [Recursive call script](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/353211/recursive-call-script), but I'm not sure the issue is the same.

**EDIT**

My goal is to basically change environment variables, aliases, etc.  So in my bash script I would originally have things such as:

```
export WORKNAME="br-190"
export BRANCH="~/$WORKNAME"
export WORKSPACE="~/workspace-${WORKNAME}"

alias sw='cd $BRANCH/source'
alias fix='mv ~/.good-files $WORKSPACE'

switch() {
   ... See Above ...
}
```

The goal is to change `WORKNAME` on the command line, such as

`switch br-104`

Comment: You should not edit `.bashrc` within `.bashrc`, you will most likely break it. Instead edit your question and tell us what you final goal is. I'm sure it can be achieved without editing `.bashrc` in itself.

Comment: Chaos is very correct. This feels both dangerous and wrong. Why not do this in another file and source that instead?

Comment: .bashrc is *sourced* not *called*.  I don't see a recursive call in `setup()`.  If I understand your goal, I think the final line in the `else` clause should be something like `. ~/.bashrc` or `source ~/.bashrc` which would source into the current environment .bashrc.  However, my instinct says this should be avoided, or at the very least, done with *great care*.

Answer (score 1):

The first, obvious issue is this:

```
if [ -z "EXISTS" ]; then
```

That will *always* be true since you are checking whether the *string* `EXISTS` is empty. Since it's a string, it will never be empty. You want to do this instead:

```
if [ -z "$EXISTS" ]; then
```

Also, it is bad practice to use `ls` for this sort of thing and it is bad practice to use CAPS for script variable names. Only use capitals for environment variables so you can be sue there will be no name overlaps.

The next major issue is that you are calling `./$0`. `$0` is `bash` so `./$0` is `./bash` which doesn't exist. What you want to do, presumably, is re-read `.bashrc`.

Then, of course, your `sed` command (even after correcting the syntax error) will always match itself. You need to make sure that you skip the line with the actual sed command, for example by only matching at the beginning of the line (also note the corrections):

```
sed -i "/^export BRANCH=/{s/export BRANCH=.*$/export BRANCH="$1\"/}" ~/.bashrc
```

But you can simplify to:

```
sed -i "s/^export BRANCH=.*$/export BRANCH="$1\"/" ~/.bashrc
```

Putting this together, you probably want something like:

```
switch() {
  shopt -s nullglob
  exists=(~/br/*"$1")
  if [ -z "$exists" ]; then
    ## Are you sure you want the * there? That will expand to all
    ## files and directories beginning with $1
    BR="$1*"
    export PS1="...."
  else
    # Find "export BRANCH"a"
    sed -i "s/export BRANCH=.*$/export BRANCH=\"$1\"/" ~/.bashrc
    . ~/.bashrc
    fi
}
```

Comment: Thanks for the detailed answer.  I do have `EXISTS` as `$EXISTS`, typo.  As far as  `sed` I only want the first occurance of `export BRANCH=` which is why I have the `{0,` , which is what I want but I don't see how the sed line will ever match itself, but thanks for the `^` reminder. Will give it a go.

Comment: @jiveturkey ah, you're right. I think I just removed the `0,` by mistake when I copied your function to play with it.

Comment: The reason I expand, `(~/br/*"$1")` is, the $1 is expected to be the name of `WORKNAME` but in the ~/br/ directory it is pre-pended with the user, i.e. bob issues the command `switch br-201` but the directory contains `~/br/bob-br-201`

Comment: When using the `shopt -s nullglob` line, `exists` is ALWAYS empty.

Comment: @jiveturkey OK, but if there are more than 1 files matching that glob, you might get unexpected consequences. I really can't help feeling this isn't the best approach here and would urge you to post a new question explaining what you are trying to do to see if anyone can come up with a better way.

Comment: @jiveturkey if `$exists` is empty, there is nothing matching the glob.

Comment: I gotta run but thanks everyone for your help.

Answer (score 0):

When `.bashrc` is being sourced, the running command is simply called `bash`.

Which in turn means the `./$0` expands to

```
./bash
```

And because `bash` is not a file in the current directory, you get that error message.
You don't want to execute it, you want to source it, therefore there must be a space between `.` and the filename. Otherwise, `.` references the current working directory.

```
. ~/.bashrc
```

Comment: Didn't seem to work

Comment: This comment is sure gonna help me figure out what the problem is...

Comment: @jiveturkey when you say something "didn't work", you're not giving us any useful information. How did it fail? Did it do nothing? Did it do something but not what you wanted? What? Were there error messages? How did you try it? If you don't give us such details, a simple "didn't work" is not at all informative.

Comment: Yeah, thanks, I was just being lazy.  It gave me the exact error as last time.  Thanks for the explanation of the error, make sense.  But even when sourcing(re-reading) it, gives no different result.(i.e. same error message)